# PacketFence Installation?

Tags: linux, network-monitoring, open-source

So I've stumbled across PacketFence during my search for a decent Network Access Control system. After doing a little research about it's capabilities I've come to realize it's meets all the requirements that I was looking for. Unfortunately, being primarily a MS Administrator, I'm having many issues trying to successfully getting it up and running. Is there anyone or any place that has a step-by-step tutorial on how to do this? I love the prospect of using Open Source software, but need some help jumping this particular hurdle.

I'm trying to use CentOS for the OS but I'm open to alternatives if thats what it takes to get this system up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Our newly released PacketFence ZEN 2.0 has both a VMware ESX and VMware Workstation version that you could try.

http://www.packetfence.org/download/vmware_appliance_zen.html

If you go with the ZEN option make sure you follow the ZEN Install Guide available in the documentation section of the website.

Please note that if you install the VM on a Windows host make sure that the network card driver supports multiple VLAN. This is driver/hardware dependent on Windows **and most don't support it**.

If the options stated above don't work for you, I would say go with CentOS. This is the platform where we focus so I would recommend sticking to it especially if you have little linux experience.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried with CentOS, but you can take a look at this [Guide](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/386610-install-packetfence-for-powerful-network-access-control) using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It's a slightly older release but [this](http://www.packetfence.org/download/vmware_appliance_zen.html) vmware appliance may be helpful.  I'm a Windows admin as well and whenever I need to run a Linux app I try for the virtual appliance to at least test it out.  If you like it enough you can then try the Linux version to be up to date.